# Unique Values in a Comma Separated List / Unique Values in Multiple Columns

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have some Google Form Data from several surveys that were conducted, where the answer categories shifted across time. I want to find out all the unique choices that were used, followed by the count of all of them.

The count will be easy, but I can't seem to extract a unique list of answers with any of the formulas I've used.

Simply put, I can't separate the values and get unique values for my data, which looks a bit like this:

```
A1, A2, A3, A7, A8
A2, A5, A3
A3, A7, A15,
A10
A11
A7, A19
etc.
```

Ideally, it'd look like this:

```
A1
A2
A3
A5
A7
A8
A10
A11
A15
A19
```

From here, I could do a `countif` formula with

> `Concatenate("*", A1, "*")`

I've made a google sheet where I've tried numerous methods: Query, Split with Array Formula, Split with TextJoin and combinations of all of them. But I'm not able to get his all into one Column

Here's the sheet with my attempts:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1179QKxGEaDhlejm2D_opdt2TwtdUrtWrbBMCkriBpvE/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(
 FILTER(Data!A:A, Data!A:A<>""), "(,)( )([A-Z])", "♦$2$3")&"♦",,999^99), "♦")))))
```

[image: 0]

### ______________________________________________________________

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(
 FILTER(Data!A:A, Data!A:A<>""), "(,)( )([A-Z])", "♦$2$3")&"♦",,999^99), "♦"))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks!

So, I understand the majority of this, but can you explain to me the query portion...

How does this section of the code work?
&"♦",,999^99

Comment: @khabibul35 sure. 999^99 is just a big number. could be any big number like 1000000 or 9999... the issue comes if its too small - then the query trick to join all rows in one cell will fail. and as already mentioned after joining all rows into one cell we need to add &"♦" to every row so SPLIT would correctly cut the string exactly where needed

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 regex.

This first -
**---------------------**
Context: global
Find: `(?:\b(A\d*)\b,?\h*(?=[\S\s]*\b\1\b))+|(A\d*),?\h*`
Replace:  `$2`

Then run this one -
**---------------------**
Context: global
Find:  `(?:(A\d*)(?=A))`
Replace:  `$1\r\n`

After you're done, sort the text alphabetically.
It will then look like this (depends on sort)  -

A1
A2
A3
A5
A7
A8
A10
A11
A15
A19

Note - if your regex engine doesn't support lookahead assertions, this method won't work.
If your regex engine doesn't support horizontal whitespace construct `\h*`, use this
instead `[^\S\r\n]*`